# How to change values in an array when comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"}];
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA"}];
```

I want output to be like this:

```
[{"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA","location":"mumbai","age":"22"}];
```

using javascript and underscorejs

My attempt is as below:

```
var workingValues = _.filter(array1, function(item){ return item});
console.log(workingValues); 
var validItems = []; 

for(var i =0 ; i < array2.length; i++){ 
  var item = array2[i]; 
  console.log(item); 

  var findItems = _.filter(array1,function(ite) {
    return ite.name.toUpperCase() == item.name.toUpperCase() && ite.surname.toUpperCase() == item.surname.toUpperCase()}); 
  validItems.push(item); 
  console.log(findItems); 
}
```

Comment: `i want` Have you tried writing any code yourself yet in an attempt to accomplish what you want? Please post it if you want debugging help

Comment: Please include the code of whatever you have tried. This site can only help with specific problems and won't be doing your whole homework or job.

Comment: var arr =_.filter(array1, function(item){ return item});

Comment: var workingValues = _.filter(array1, function(item){ return item});
        console.log(workingValues);

        var validItems = [];
       
        for(var i =0 ; i < array2.length; i++){
            var item = array2[i];
            console.log(item);
  
       var findItems = _.filter(array1,function(ite) {return  ite.name.toUpperCase() == item.name.toUpperCase() && ite.surname.toUpperCase() == item.surname.toUpperCase()});
         validItems.push(item);
         
        console.log(findItems);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"},{"name":"sam123","surname":"sameera123","location":"mumbai","age":"22"} ];
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA"},{"name":"SAM123","surname":"SAMEERA123"}];

var ret = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i += 1) {
  var newArray = array2.filter(function (el) {
      return el.name.toUpperCase() == array1[i].name.toUpperCase() &&                                                  el.surname.toUpperCase() ==array1[i].surname.toUpperCase();
  });
  if(newArray.length ==0)
  {
     ret.push(array1[i]);    
  }
  else
  {
     array1[i].name = newArray[0].name; //change valuse
     array1[i].surname = newArray[0].surname; //change valuse
     ret.push(array1[i]);
  }
};
   

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"},{"name":"sam123","surname":"sameera123","location":"mumbai","age":"22"}....etc
];
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA"},{"name":"SAM123","surname":"SAMEERA123"}....etc];
how can i do this bro

Comment: @pradeep I have updated my code. please check and if any issues please let me know.

Comment: var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"},{"name":"sam123","surname":"sameera123","location":"mumbai","age":"22"} ]; 
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA"},{"name":"SAM123","surname":"SAMEERA123"}];
please  check this

Comment: @pradeep Sorry I do not know undesorejs.

Comment: @pradeep ok checking

Comment: @pradeep I have updated my code. please check and I do not found any issues.

Comment: how can i follow u in stackoverflow

Comment: @pradeep Can you mark this answer correct if it is useful? for follow 

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/is-there-a-way-to-follow-peoples-activity

It's my pleasure someone wants to follow me.

Comment: @pradeep Can you mark this answer correct if it is useful?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"}];
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"SAMEERA"}];

var result = [{...array1[0],...array2[0]}];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: please use underscorejs or other normal javascript methods and dont use ...array[0]
i have multiple array objects

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited data you've provided.

```js
var array1 = [ {"name":"sam","surname":"sameera","location":"mumbai","age":"22"}];
var array2 =[ {"name":"SAM","surname":"sameera"}];
console.log( _.extend(array2, array1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want output like this  [
  {
    "name": "SAM",
    "surname": "sameera",
    "location": "mumbai",
    "age": "22"
  }
]
but here does not change the value sam as SAM

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array1 = [{
    "name":"sam",
    "surname":"sameera",
    "location":"mumbai",
    "age":"22"
}];
var array2 =[{
    "name":"SAM",
    "surname":"sameera"
}];
var mergearray= array1 .concat(array2);
```